# Google Places API autocomplete not working

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Right now, the autocomplete box works just fine when I click on the location, but when I press down, highlight the location that I want to go to, and press enter, it simply goes back to the home location of the map. Any insights on this? I call this function in initialize(). I'm lost as to what I possibly did wrong. Is this just a google api bug? If so, any insights as to how to work around it?

```
function setupAutoComplete() {
    var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(-90, -180),
        new google.maps.LatLng(90, 180));

    var input = document.getElementById('placeSearch');
    var options = {
        bounds: defaultBounds,
        types: ['(regions)']
    };
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        alert('hi'); 
        removeAllOverlays();
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        var mapCenter = place.geometry.location;
        var colLat = mapCenter.lat() - (halfPoints)*latSeparation;
        var colLng = mapCenter.lng() - (halfPoints)*lngSeparation;
        var tempStart = new google.maps.LatLng(colLat, colLng);
        map.setCenter(mapCenter);
        pointArray[0][0] = tempStart;
        reService();
        mapSearch();
        drawBounds();
    });
}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean here:  "...but when I press down, highlight the location that I want to go to, and press enter.."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the `input#placeSearch` is placed inside a `<form>`.

You submit the form when you press [ENTER].

You may either remove the surrounding form or cancel the submission by adding:

```
onsubmit="return false"
```

...to the form-element.

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed the problem! I spent so long trying to fix it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this issue and went with the following, as I do want to submit the form at a later stage. This code is from [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/9v29754Vg0o).

```
var input = document.getElementById('create-location');
var options = {
    //types: ['(cities)'],
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(input, 'keydown', function(e) { 
    if (e.keyCode == 13) 
    { 
        if (e.preventDefault) 
        { 
            e.preventDefault(); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            // Since the google event handler framework does not handle  early IE versions, we have to do it by our self. :-( 
            e.cancelBubble = true; 
            e.returnValue = false; 
        } 
    } 
});
```